# jQuery .find() and .after() not working properly

Tags: jquery, append, prepend

I'm trying to check whether an element exists inside another element which is the parent element, and if it doesn't, then insert a HTML after a child of the parent element, using the following approach:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('.1').each(function($){
        if(jQuery(this).find('.intruder').length == 0){
            jQuery('.1b').after('<div class="pull-left item-image"><div class="specialthumbnail-nopicture"></div></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

Desired HTML result:

```
<div class="1">
        <div class="1a">Something else</div>
        <div class="1b">Something else</div>
        <div class="intruder">HTML goes here</div>
        <div class="1c">Something else</div>
</div>
```

What I'm getting is that when the `intruder` class already exists in the DOM, then I get two `intruder` elements:

```
 <div class="1">
            <div class="1a">Something else</div>
            <div class="1b">Something else</div>
            <div class="intruder">HTML goes here</div>
            <div class="intruder">HTML goes here</div>
            <div class="1c">Something else</div>
    </div>
```

So basically it is not recognizing that the element is already there, and it's inserting a new one, thus resulting in a duplicate.

EDIT

Solved it by changing:

```
jQuery('.1b').after
```

to

```
jQuery(this).find('.1b').after
```

Please tell me if that approach is acceptable..

Comment: Quick side note; if you remove the `$` from the `each` function, then you can use $ every where inside that document ready as you are passing jQuery in as $

Comment: Thx for the tip. Only one `.1`

Comment: `$(this).find(thing)` is the same as `$(thing, this)` of which both are contextual lookups.  Yes that is a valid solution.

Comment: Did not find any issue with your implementation : https://jsfiddle.net/dq8xayqc/2/

Comment: BTW, you can use `$(".1:not(:has(.intruder))")` to find all `.1` that don't have `.intruder` nested in them.

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform contextual lookups for the children, rather than global lookups, so you do not affect other elements children.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.1').each(function() {
    //target the intruder inside this '1'
    if ($('.intruder', this).length == 0) {
      //target the 1b inside this '1'
      $('.1b', this).after('<div class="pull-left item-image"><div class="specialthumbnail-nopicture">Weee</div></div>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">
  <div class="1a">Something else</div>
  <div class="1b">Something else</div>
  <div class="intruder">HTML goes here</div>
  <div class="1c">Something else</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="1">
  <div class="1a">Something else</div>
  <div class="1b">Something else</div>
  <div class="1c">Something else</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I need to affect other elements children. It's a cards layout.